# switch to new window not working in IE11 windows 7 in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

when I am manually clicking on a link it opens a new tab but while I am doing automation its opening as a new window but in console its showing that it has not switched to the new window and is not able to perform any other operation on the new window

And according to the script it should click on a link, switch the new window and perform operations on the new window.

IE VERSION IS IE-11 Windows7

Comment: what is your firefox version?

Comment: could you please share you code? @user7040537

Comment: Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println(handles);
      Iterator<String> itr = handles.iterator();
         Object   firstHandle = itr.next();
      Object   lastHandle = firstHandle;
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
         lastHandle = itr.next();
         
         
         
     }
    WebDriver  popup=  driver.switchTo().window(lastHandle.toString());

Comment: I have to use IE only, firefox I am not using.